# How to read Textbox which is inside Ajax tab control into javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

How to read the `Textbox` which is inside `Ajax tab container`. This is my design

```
<ajax:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" CssClass="fancy fancy-green">
        <ajax:TabPanel ID="tbpnluser" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                New User
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="UserReg" runat="server">
                    <table align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <b>Registration Form</b>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                UserName:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtuser" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajax:TabPanel>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function alert() {
        var value = document.getElementById("TabContainer1_tbpnluser_txtuser").value;
        alert(value);
    }
</script>
```

This is how my textbox is

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtuser" onblur="alert();" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I would like to read the `textbox` from `javascript` can any one help me

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var value = document.getElementById('<%=TextBoxID.ClientID%>').value;
```

Read more about [Get TextBox value using JavaScript](http://www.dotneter.com/get-textbox-value-using-javascript)

Update
If its not working try something like this

```
document.getElementById("TabContainer1_tbpnluser_txtuser").value;
```

Comment: As I am having textbox inside `TabContainer ` this didn't work for me

Comment: what value you get when you use this??

Comment: I am getting an error as `The name 'txtUser' does not exist in the current context` if I write like that

Comment: Thanks but I am not able to alert the text box value onblur

Comment: @Vivekh: Did you add **onblur()** as Attribute to textbox??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10885/discussion-between-vivekh-and-humpty-dumpty)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var value = $('#<%=txtuser.ClientID%>').value;
alert(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try instead of this
if its work

```
var value =$find("txtuser");
alert(value)
```